# Problem with .NET Razor + syncfusion autocomplete

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to add [syncfusion autocomplete](https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components/blazor-autocomplete) component to my Blazor WebAssembly App. I did everything according to the [instructions](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/autocomplete/getting-started?_gl=1*rtofzw*_ga*MTk2NjMwMjc0Ni4xNjU1Mjg5MTUw*_ga_WC4JKKPHH0*MTY1NTMxMzM2MS4zLjEuMTY1NTMxNDUxNy4w&_ga=2.232040732.2048879901.1655289150-1966302746.1655289150). It should provides a text box with a list of suggestions to select from as the user types.

Something like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4tGM.png)

But I have like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsEAB.png).
That is, without list of suggestions.

My question is: why is this happening and how to fix it?

Perhaps this is due to errors in index.html?

```html
<link href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Core/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```html
Cannot resolve file 'StockMarket.Client.styles.css'
Cannot resolve directory '_content'
Cannot resolve directory 'Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes'
Cannot resolve file 'bootstrap5.css'
Cannot resolve directory '_content'
Cannot resolve directory 'Syncfusion.Blazor.Core'
Cannot resolve directory 'scripts'
Cannot resolve file 'syncfusion-blazor.min.js'
Cannot resolve directory '_framework'
Cannot resolve file 'blazor.webassembly.js'
```

Detailed description of my actions:

1. Installed nuget package Syncfusion.Blazor
2. Added this code to Program.cs in client side

```cs
using Syncfusion.Blazor;

builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor(options => { options.IgnoreScriptIsolation = true; });
```

3. Added style sheet to index.html in client side

```html
<link href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

4. Added script reference to index.html in client side

```html
<script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Core/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

5. Added to _import.razor

```cs
@using Syncfusion.Blazor
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is caused by Resharper try installing Resharper 2020.1.3.